# Using MySQL With Visual Studio C# Error

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, connection

I am using MySQL With Visual Studio, C# and I have added the Resources required. My Code Is:

using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

```
    string MySqlConnectionValues = "SERVER=blahblahblah.000webhost.com; DATABASE=dbdbdbdb;UID=OopsIDon'tRemember; PASSWORD=whatspassword?;";
    MySqlConnection MySQLCon;
    MySqlDataAdapter MySQLDataAdapter;
    DataTable DTItems;

            private void MySQLForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            MySQLCon = new MySqlConnection(MySqlConnectionValues);
        }
        catch (Exception UnableToConnectToMYSQL)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(UnableToConnectToMYSQL.Message.ToString());
        }
    }

    DataTable GetAllItems()
    {
        try
        {
            string Query = "select * from items";

            MySQLDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(Query, MySQLCon);
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            MySQLDataAdapter.Fill(DS);
            return DS.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (Exception UnableToGetAllItems)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(UnableToGetAllItems.Message.ToString());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But I am Getting "Unable To Connect to any of the specified MySQL Hosts" Messagebox on UnableToGetAllItems Exception. While I am sure that I have entered host name exactly the same on Manage MySQLDatabases page in 000webhost CPanel. Why Is That Happening?

Comment: Looks like this is a hosted MySQL box? Are the required ports open?

Answer (score 0):

Probably your connection string is not valid from the db provider point of view. Because it contains symbols like apostrophe. Try to create a new user with plain name and see if it will work. Else you need to screen such symbols maybe using ' instead of symbol.

Comment: "Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification starting at index 0."

Comment: What is it? Error message or what?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your webhost allows you to connect to your MySQL database in this way? If it is allowed, do you know the correct port on which to connect? By default port 3306 will be used if you don't add the port to your connectionstring.